# php - Arrays, Shuffle, and Conditions

Tags: php

I created a quiz that generates a random answer by using the `shuffle()` function.
Everything is working with the array and shuffle.

The next thing I want to do is when the answer generates. (Toyota is an example.)

> "Toyota"

the description would say:

> "Toyota is a great car, made in this city, has a great gas mileage."

My code:

```
<?php

// Array of the vehicles
$answer = array(
"Mercedes", 
"Benz", 
"Honda", 
"Toyota", 
"Nissan", 
"Mazda", 
"Hyundai", 
"Ford", 
"Lexus", 
"Lamborghini", 
"Ferrari", 
"Porche", 
"Mitsubushi", 
"Scion", 
"Chrysler", 
"Jeep", 
"Masarati"
);

// Shuffle Array
shuffle($answer);

// Echo ONE item only.
echo $answer[0];

?>
```

I **think** I need to use conditions to do this.

For example: I attempted but it didn't work.

```
<?php
// If array VALUE 0 is equal to Toyota after it's shuffled.
if($answer[0]=='Toyota')
{
    echo "Toyota is a great car! You should buy it.";
}
if($answer[1]=='Benz')
{
    echo "Benz is a great car.";
}

?>
```

Thanks in advance. Appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of the shuffle is this  `$answer[0];`

so in your if you do not need this `$answer[1];`,`$answer[2];`.... etc

just like  `$answer[0];` :

```
if($answer[0]=='Toyota')
{
    echo "Toyota is a great car! You should buy it.";
}
if($answer[0]=='Benz')
{
    echo "Benz is a great car.";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use arrays associatively:

```
 $comments = array(
    "Toyota" => 'Toyota is a great car! You should buy it.',
    'Benz' => 'Benz is a great car.',
    // etc.
);

isset($comments[$answer[0]]) && echo $comments[$answer[0]];
```

Comment: I might switch that way if its better.

Answer (score 3):

That conditioning you want to do is going to be rather tedious and un-needed. (*All those `if` blocks*).
Why not set up an array that holds the descriptions like this:

```
$descriptions = array(
"Mercedes" => 'is like fast food', 
"Benz" => 'sometimes', 
"Honda" => 'just your descriptions', 
...... etc
```

And then do the shuffle like you're doing now, then grab the description from the array like this:

```
// Shuffle Array
shuffle($answer);

// Echo ONE item only.
echo $answer[0];

if(isset($descriptions[$answer[0]])) {
    echo $descriptions[$answer[0]];
}
```

Comment: @MartinShaba Perfectly alright, let me know how it goes.